# <input> not retrieved using Flask in Python

Tags: python, html, forms, flask

I am creating a simple form in python.

Here is the HTML:

```
<form class="msger-inputarea" action="{{url_for('get_learn')}}" method="post">
<input name ="my_msg" id="my_msg" type="text" class="msger-input" placeholder="Enter your message...">
<button onclick="msg_sent()" type="submit" class="msger-send-btn">Send</button>
</form>
```

And here is the Python Flask code:

```
def get_learn():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        new_question = str(request.form.get("my_msg"))
        print(new_question)

        return render_template('learn.html')
```

`print(new_question)` prints `None`

It appears that request.form is an empty dict.
`print(request.form)` returns `ImmutableMultiDict([])`

It should be having my_msg, which should be what the user has inputed.

Comment: Try using the browsers dev tools to check on the the request, and make sure it's as expected.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid having to worry about whether it's POST or GET or whether you're trying to get the data from a form, use `request.values.get(<elem_name>, <default_value>)`

i.e.

`request.values.get('my_msg', None)`

Comment: This still returns None. request.values = CombinedMultiDict([ImmutableMultiDict([]), ImmutableMultiDict([])])

Comment: Add your complete code for ```get_learn``` showing you using ```request.values.get```

Comment: Its the same code but I replaced 'request.form.get("my_msg")' with 'request.values.get("my_msg")'

Comment: I just tested your code and it worked. There's probably something different on your end or maybe you're using an older version of Flask?